# Get maximal level of embedding of element in recursively nested XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

For every element in an arbitrarily recursively nested XML I need to find its maximal level of embedding.

So for example for this XML

```xml
<chorus>
    <l>Alright now lose it <ah>aah <i>aah <ah>a<ah>a</ah>h</ah> aah</i> aah</ah></l>
    <l>Just lose it aah aah aah aah aah</l>
    <l>Go crazy aah aah aah aah aah</l>
    <l>Oh baby <ah>aah aah</ah>, oh baby baby <ah>aah aah</ah></l>
</chorus>
```

the output should look like: `{"chorus": 0, "l": 0, "ah": 2, "i": 0}`

Unfortunately the solution is limited to the use of `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

I tried different approaches for hours but I can't get my head wrapped around it.

Comment: @mzjn `<chorus>` and `<l>` aren't embedded in themselves, but `<ah>` is embedded two times in itself. That's what I mean with "maximal level of embedding". Sorry, if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a modified version of [this example from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xmlparser-objects):

[image]

Try changing `maxDepth` and `depth` to dictionaries using the element name (tag) for the key...

**Python**

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser


class MaxDepth:  # The target object of the parser
    maxDepth = {}
    depth = {}

    def start(self, tag, attrib):  # Called for each opening tag.
        try:
            self.depth[tag] += 1
        except KeyError:
            self.depth[tag] = 0
            self.maxDepth[tag] = 0
        if self.depth[tag] > self.maxDepth[tag]:
            self.maxDepth[tag] = self.depth[tag]

    def end(self, tag):  # Called for each closing tag.
        self.depth[tag] -= 1

    def data(self, data):
        pass  # We do not need to do anything with data.

    def close(self):  # Called when all data has been parsed.
        return self.maxDepth


target = MaxDepth()
parser = XMLParser(target=target)
exampleXml = """
<chorus>
    <l>Alright now lose it <ah>aah <i>aah <ah>a<ah>a</ah>h</ah> aah</i> aah</ah></l>
    <l>Just lose it aah aah aah aah aah</l>
    <l>Go crazy aah aah aah aah aah</l>
    <l>Oh baby <ah>aah aah</ah>, oh baby baby <ah>aah aah</ah></l>
</chorus>"""
parser.feed(exampleXml)
print(parser.close())
```

**Output**

```
{'chorus': 0, 'l': 0, 'ah': 2, 'i': 0}
```

**Edited Python** (where `chorus` is already an `ElementTree.Element` object)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser


class MaxDepth:  # The target object of the parser
    maxDepth = {}
    depth = {}

    def start(self, tag, attrib):  # Called for each opening tag.
        try:
            self.depth[tag] += 1
        except KeyError:
            self.depth[tag] = 0
            self.maxDepth[tag] = 0
        if self.depth[tag] > self.maxDepth[tag]:
            self.maxDepth[tag] = self.depth[tag]

    def end(self, tag):  # Called for each closing tag.
        self.depth[tag] -= 1

    def data(self, data):
        pass  # We do not need to do anything with data.

    def close(self):  # Called when all data has been parsed.
        return self.maxDepth


exampleXml = """
<chorus>
    <l>Alright now lose it <ah>aah <i>aah <ah>a<ah>a</ah>h</ah> aah</i> aah</ah></l>
    <l>Just lose it aah aah aah aah aah</l>
    <l>Go crazy aah aah aah aah aah</l>
    <l>Oh baby <ah>aah aah</ah>, oh baby baby <ah>aah aah</ah></l>
</chorus>"""

chorus_element = ET.fromstring(exampleXml)

target = MaxDepth()
parser = XMLParser(target=target)
parser.feed(ET.tostring(chorus_element))
print(parser.close())
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly! Thank you! However I'm not sure, how I can integrate this if `<chorus>` is already a parsed `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` object?

Comment: @DanielMacDaniel - Since `feed()` needs encoded data, you should be able to use `tostring()` to serialize the ElementTree.Element (`<chorus>`) and use that in feed(). Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good use case for the function str.find(string, begining, end) : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm

So if I understood correctly for each element between <> we'll look the maximum embedding depth of this element, so :

- We look for the element, we save the position at which we find it
- We then look for the the closing matching element, save the position
- look for the element again, but starting after the position at which we found it the first time
- if the position of the second occurence of element is found before the first occurence of the closing element, we add 1 to depth and we will start looking after the position of this second occurence
- if the position of the second occurence of the element is found after the first occurence of the closing element, they are not embedded, so we do not update the depth and we will be looking after the position of the closing element to find the nexts closing elements
- repeat until you do not find the element in the substring anymore
- repeat for every different element

I think it's totaly optimizable but after a few testing it works :

```
import re

string = ("<chorus>"
          "<l>Alright now lose it <ah>aah <i>aah <ah>a<ah>a</ah>h</ah> aah</i> aah</ah></l>"
          "<l>Just lose it aah aah aah aah aah</l>"
          "<l>Go crazy aah aah aah aah aah</l>"
          "<l>Oh baby <ah>aah aah</ah>, oh baby baby <ah>aah aah</ah></l>"
          "</chorus>")

# Start looking for the different nodes
regex = re.compile('\<[a-z]+\>')
# create a set of the nodes and closing nodes so we can iterate trough them
nodes = set(regex.findall(string))
closing_nodes = [node.replace('<', '</') for node in nodes]


depth = {node: '0' for node in nodes}

for node, closing_node in zip(nodes, closing_nodes):
    pos_node = string.find(node) + len(node)
    pos_closing_node = 0
    node_depth = 0
    max_node_depth = 0
    # we keep looking until we do not find our node (then str.find(node) returns -1)
    while pos_node >= 0:
        pos_closing_node = string.find(closing_node, pos_closing_node)
        pos_node = string.find(node, pos_node)
        # if we didnt find the node at all of if we found an occurence of a closing node before the node, we reduce depth by 1
        # and we will be looking for the next closing node next time, so we add the lengh of the closing node to the starting position of our search
        if pos_closing_node < pos_node or pos_node == -1:
            node_depth -= 1
            pos_closing_node = pos_closing_node + len(closing_node)
        else:
            node_depth += 1
            pos_node = pos_node + len(node)
        # we want the max depth so we take the max of the depth values
        max_node_depth = max(max_node_depth, node_depth)
    depth[node] = max_node_depth

print(depth)
```

Comment: Thank you for your work and your suggestion, but unfortunately in my case a `str.find` approach isn't very suitable. My program parses large XML files with `xml.etree.ElementTree` and finding the maximum embedding depth of each element is only a by product. `Beautifulsoup` for example has a nice method `find_parents()`, that could simplify that a lot, but because I'm adding this function to a larger code base, I'm stuck to using `xml.etree.ElementTree` as I wrote.